# Using the session variable after logging and in other php file

Tags: php, mysql, session

Please see the following code:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
<html> ............... </html>
```

Should we use the part of the code below in each `php` file that is shown below?

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
........... ?>
```

I learned creating the **login.php** and **profile.php** using this [site](http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/).But when I see the **profile.php** it uses the part of the code above: Checking the connection and database and then using the `$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];` and then using the following code:

```
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
```

If I have another `php` file such as the following code to use the payment gateways:

**send.php**

```
<?php
include_once("sender.php");
$url = 'http://example.com/payment/gateway-send';
$api = ' Your-API ';
$amount = 1000;
$redirect = 'REDIRECT-PAGE';
$result = send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect);
if($result > 0 && is_numeric($result)){
$go = "http://example.com/payment/gateway-$result";
header("Location: $go");
}
?>
```

Should I add the following code in the beginning of the `send.php` file and also for other `php` files?

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql); 
.................?>
```

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: @Prashant Srivastav: I want know How can I use session in in each php file? should I add the latest code from my post in other my php files ?

Comment: You will need `session_start()` in each page where you want to use `$_SESSION` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should to create a connection file say connection.php with the code -

```
    <?php
    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection); 
?>
```

And another file security.php to set session variables.

```
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql = mysql_query("select username from login where username = '$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
.................?>
```

And include those two files at the beginning of all the php files.

At send.php I can't find any db related operation or session check. So it is not needed to include those two files at send.php .